# How to use external namespaces for types in TypeScript / TSX

Tags: typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working with some scripts of [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/) (and some other external scripts like Intercom) in TypeScript by loading them through a script tag. With most of them, I have issues, because I don't have types from them that I can actually import and use.

For example with Facebook, I've installed the package `@types/facebook-js-sdk` from `DefinitelyTyped`, which allows me to see the type of `window.FB`, because it's declared in the namespace from the types package. However, I can't seem to use or import any type to type `window.FB` when I'm passing it to some other code for example, see code below.

```
// window.FB is typed here
const fb = new Facebook(window.FB)
```

```
class Facebook {
  // How can I type fb here?
  constructor(fb) {
    this.fb = fb
  }
```

Is there any way I can use the namespace to get types? Do I need to write the types myself in this case? Open to suggestions!

Comment: Also, I think sort of relevant question to this: Why are definitely typed packages always namespaces, and not (exported) types/interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type for your typed window variable by doing `typeof`.

So for example

```js
class Facebook {
  fb: typeof window.FB

  constructor(fb: typeof window.FB) {
    if (typeof fb === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('The Facebook API is not initialized!')
    }

    this.fb = fb
  }
}
```